# How can I run mysql replication on a single host?

Tags: mysql, replication, database-replication

I'd like to replicate a mysql database on a single host and then take snapshots of the replicated DB for development, ie:

Master -> Repslave (readonly) -> multiple development snapshots

The snapshots should only store the differences between themselves and the repslave as it was at the point in time that the snapshot was taken. The repslave should continue requesting updated actions from the master so that future snapshots are up to date. I've seen this done before and found it very useful to develop on but I don't know much about setting it up.

How is this done? I'd prefer not to place two installations of mysql on the same host if possible. Is this also feasible?